# How to join pieces of images into one with using FFmpeg API?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav

I have parts of one image like

- 0x0_img1.jpg
- 100x200_img1.jpg
- 300x0_img1.jpg
- 360x420_img1.jpg
- 1080x720_img1.jpg

I just want to know how to merge these into a single image.

Image name has quadrants details (0x0 , 100x200... etc,.), which are the start position of the parts to the orginal image

Now how do I merge these parts of images using the FFMPEG c lib

Comment: Could you update your answer and show what you have already tried? Maybe also point out the documenation you read and how that didn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hstack filter [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack)

ffmpeg -i 1.jpg -i 2.jpg -filter_complex hstack output

Comment: you can use system function or popen  function and pass this command as parameter